# Combining Overlapping String Sets into a Single Set using Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have several sets of strings, and my goal is to combine them into a single set using Kusto. All sets that have at least one shared element need to be combined.

Here's an example of the input data:

```
["Apple", "Banana"]
["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]
["Banana", "Cherry"]
["Nissan", "Mazda"]
["Giraffe", "Hare", "Ibis"]
["Hare", "Ibis", "Jellyfish"]
```

The output should be like this:

```
[ "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]
["Nissan","Mazda"]
["Giraffe","Hare","Ibis","Jellyfish"]
```

Kusto lacks built-in support for loops, such as `while`, which could simplify this operation. I considered using `join` to combine sets with shared elements, followed by `summarize` or `reduce` for the desired output. However, I couldn't determine how to continue this process until all combined sets were created.

Answer (score 0):

Kusto does not know that an Apple is a fruit and Mazda is a car. For this reason you need to define this in your dataset. Then it works without "while" on three categories fruit, car and animal with a simple union:

```
let mydata = datatable(myid:int, type:string, myvalues:string  )
[
1,"fruit", "Apple,Banana",
2,"fruit","Apple,Banana,Cherry",
3,"fruit", "Banana,Cherry",
4,"car", "Nissan,Mazda",
5, "animal" ,"Giraffe,Hare,Ibis",
6, "animal" ,"Hare,Ibis,Jellyfish"
];
let fruit  = mydata
| where type =="fruit" 
| extend myitem = split(myvalues, ",")
| mv-expand myitem
| extend myitem = tostring(myitem)
| distinct  myitem
| summarize make_list(myitem);
let car  = mydata
| where type =="car"
| extend myitem = split(myvalues, ",")
| mv-expand myitem
| extend myitem = tostring(myitem)
| distinct  myitem
| summarize make_list(myitem);
let animal  = mydata
| where type =="animal" 
| extend myitem = split(myvalues, ",")
| mv-expand myitem
| extend myitem = tostring(myitem)
| distinct  myitem
| summarize make_list(myitem);
fruit | union car | union animal
```

[image]